# Icmp monitoring using visual c# .net

Tags: c#, icmp

I want to write an application that monitors some of my remote branches. I want to monitor 2 things

1) icmp drop (if i send 10 pings and 2 or more are dropped then alert)
2) if latency of ping is above 20 ms then alert.

I have just defined the rough thresholds. Can it be done in visual c#, Basically i am learning c# and also doing stuff for my office so that my learning is in right direction. If you guys can point me in right direction i will be grateful. I have seen ping class in .net (on google i mean) but i think it only tells whether the IP is up or not.

Kindly guide me

Comment: Note: Exiting the debugger while waiting for a `PingReply` on .NET 4, **WILL** cause a BSOD. I suggest you stick to .NET 3.5. https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/691615/stopping-debugging-session-while-waiting-for-pingreply-causes-bsod

Comment: How do you connect to the remotes?

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly easy thing to do.

First you need the winpcap driver http://www.winpcap.org/ which you may already have if you have anything like wireshark installed.

Once you have the winpcap driver you then either need 'SharpPcap' the .NET library to interface to WinPcap:

```
http://www.tamirgal.com/blog/page/SharpPcap.aspx
```

or you can wrap it yourself using P/Invoke and other unmanaged goodies...

```
http://dranaxum.wordpress.com/2010/11/20/using-winpcap-in-c/
http://geekswithblogs.net/dotnetnomad/archive/2008/01/31/119140.aspx
```

Comment: how will that be useful to me ?
also, the task is very simple, just to monitor how many ping packets were dropped out of 10, so for that i need to interface with winpcap ?
ok i might do that, but is there a easy way ?

Comment: There may be other ways to do this, as with anything programming (101 ways to skin a cat and all that) but for low level scenarios where I've needed to capture and anlayse non application packet traffic, winpcap and sharpcap have always served me well.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the code in this project.
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/CSharpPing.aspx